# How to add the below red marked option inside select/select2 filed

Tags: jquery, html

I am using select2 here.Please help.Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is outside of the select2-results, which are the "option" elements inside the select itself. So you have to check what is the container's class and select it with JQuery. Make sure you make it after the page and the plugin is loaded and the simply append the html with javascript to that container.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select2-container').append('<a href="#" class="my-class-for-this-row">+ New Customer</a>');
});
```